# Lowest catagory link

Tags: categories, theme-development

I am trying to display lowest child category link.At this point I can only display the child category name but I want it with permalink.So far my approach

```
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

foreach($categories as $category) :
    $children = get_categories( array ('parent' => $category->term_id ));
    $has_children = count($children);

    if ( $has_children == 0 ) {
        echo $category->name;
    }
endforeach;
```

It display the lowest category name but not with hyperlink to that category. How can I link the category?

Comment: Use [`get_category_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast done it fully

```
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

foreach($categories as $category) :

    $children = get_categories( array ('parent' => $category->term_id ));
    $category_link = get_category_link($children);
    $has_children = count($children);

    if ( $has_children == 0 ) {
        $name=$category->name;
        $category_link = get_category_link($category);
        echo "<a href='$category_link'>$name</a>";
    }
endforeach;
```